# How to make Python code that creates a dictionary that contains elements from a pre-existing dictionary that takes one key and many values?

Tags: python

I need to create a dictionary whose keys are unique course codes and whose values are dictionaries with a single key-value pair describing the sections available for that course code, in alphabetical order.

The data is from a dictionary called student_data that looks like this:

```
student_data[:3]

>>>[{'enlistment': [{'course code': 'UK 60', 'section': 'A'}, 
{'course code': 'GF 24', 'section': 'B'}, 
{'course code': 'ME 40', 'section': 'B'}, 
{'course code': 'VY 44', 'section': 'D'}, 
{'course code': 'EN 94', 'section': 'B'}], 
'id': '201001', 'paid': True, 'school': 'SOSE', 'year level': 2}, 
{'enlistment': [{'course code': 'EQ 61', 'section': 'D'}, 
{'course code': 'UZ 22', 'section': 'B'}, 
{'course code': 'KS 36', 'section': 'B'}, 
{'course code': 'VH 63', 'section': 'A'}, 
{'course code': 'IW 81', 'section': 'C'}], 
'id': '211002', 'paid': True, 'school': 'JGSOM', 'year level': 1}, 
{'enlistment': [{'course code': 'WE 15', 'section': 'D'}, 
{'course code': 'ZP 68', 'section': 'A'}, 
{'course code': 'GI 78', 'section': 'A'}, 
{'course code': 'GK 72', 'section': 'C'}, 
{'course code': 'FA 24', 'section': 'D'}, 
{'course code': 'UJ 28', 'section': 'A'}], 
'id': '201003', 'paid': True, 'school': 'JGSOM', 'year level': 2}]
```

Format of the desired output:

```
{
    course_code: {
        "sections": [sections]
    }
}
```

I've been trying to do this but I don't have a good grasp of dictionaries in Python so I've been having a difficult time. Please help.

**EDIT:**
What if I have to get the ID numbers per section as well?

Format of the desired output with ID numbers:

```
{
    course_code: [{
        "section": section_letter,
        "class list": [id_numbers]
    }]
}
```

Comment: The "desired output" isn't a valid dictionary and doesn't follow in an obvious way from the sample input.  I'd suggest starting with a smaller sample input and then generating the *actual* desired output to make your question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that understood you correctly, but maybe it should be something like this:

```
data = {}
for i in student_data:
    for j in i['enlistment']:
        if j['course code'] not in data:
            data[j['course code']] = {'sections':[j['section']]}
        else:
            data[j['course code']]['sections'].append(j['section'])
for i in data.keys():
    data[i]['sections'] = sorted(data[i]['sections'])
```